Wordpress pages do not appear after transfer to new host
Somewhat of an amateur here: I moved a wordpress site from one host to another. This involved me backing up the old site, and uploading all of the material from the wp_content folder into the wordpress installation on the new site via FTP. When I log into wp-admin, I can see the transferred plugins and themes, but not the pages. I'm guessing this has something to do with me needing to properly edit the wp-config file to point at the correct database. The database is currently sitting in the wp-content folder and simply called 'database.sql'. Could someone kindly explain where this database should sit, what it should be called, and what updates I need to make to the wp-config file please?

You have to IMPORT the database into the database that exists on the new host. You will probably have access to a tool called phpMyAdmin. You can do a little research on how to load the db using that

try a search like how to import a db to wordpress

At this point, as you said being an amateur, I think the easiest way for you to migrate a website from one host to another is using a plugin, which makes the migration way easier.
Try something like - All In One WP Migration, or Duplicator plugin
Besides that it seems that you have not migrated the Database. Just migrating the wp-content folder does not do the job.
I assume you already have an working application in the server. You need to do the following:

Locate the phpMyAdmin or a db manager in you hosting website.

Create a new database(name, username, password and host(usually localhost). Save those values because you need to edit them later in wp-config.php file.

In phpMyAdmin select the db and find the import tab and upload the database.sql file you had.

Now you should edit the wp-config.php file of your new wordpress installation directory. This meaning updating the following lines:
define('DB_NAME', 'your_database_name'); // Replace with the new database name
define('DB_USER', 'your_database_user'); // Replace with the new database username
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_database_password'); // Replace with the new database password
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); // Replace if the database host is different

Sometimes the URL also need updating in database. Test, if it needs, then go to phpMyAdmin and open the wp_options tabe, look for the rows with option_name values of you siteurl and update their value to match your new site's URL.


Let me know if this works for you or you need some more information.

This is very clear and helpful, thank you. I followed the instructions but have hit another roadblock. I successfully imported the .sql and changed the WP-Config file, but now when I go to the URL it is simply a white page. If I try to access /wp-admin, it says 'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.'

@pdunbar First, can you check that all the wp-config data regarding new database is correct. Second, Do you have an error log from the server perhaps? It seems, that the page is not getting the info from the db.

config file is definitely correct, cause I initially made a mistake with it and got the 'error connecting to database' messages. Now having fixed that I just get the white page and then also no access to wp-admin. Maybe I need to start from scratch? Perhaps remove the wordpress installation from the host? If there was somewhere with information to guide me as I have all the old wordpress material backup.

@pdunbar Okay, have you also replaced the siteurl also in the database?
Second thing you can try is regenerating the .htaccess file. This might fix the white screen.
If you were to start again and your site isn't too heavy, meaning a smaller site, then you could use all-in-one-wp-migration plugin. If it is bigger, then use the duplicator plugin.
Let me know if you need any further help!

You need to import the database file in phpmyadmin.
First create database in MySQL in your hosting
Then Create new user and link with database
now open PhpMyAdmin and click on database that you created and import database backup file in it using import option.
And finally change db name and user name & password in config.php file.
